# How to clear browser cache when launching updated version of application?

Tags: angularjs, tomcat, web-applications, gruntjs, browser-cache

I am deploying my UI application which is made up of AngularJS, Grunt and other UI things.

Whenever i update my UI and redeploy it using apache-tomcat, Browser is always getting my resources from cache. (As the path of new resources like css, html are same)

User needs to do CTRL+F5 (Hard reload) to clear cache and use new resources.

> How can i force browser to clear cache when i redeploy application?
>
> If somehow i can use angular + grunt to do this task than also it is
>   fine.

I don't want to update the versioning of my files each time i redeploy the product. As my files internally downloading many html files as well.

So somehow i want to clear the browser cache only.

Thanks!

Comment: Start with disabling cache on index.html using http headers and adding some plugin ~cache-bust something to add hashes to all your assets.

Answer (score 2):

You can't update cache without filenames versioning. But you don't have to do it manually. If you use Grunt, just check out some npm packages. Like this one for example: https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-cache-breaker

On rebuild it will create new hashes for your assets and inject them into your html files. So when your users will download your html files (they are downloaded, they are not cached), these html files will contain assets like css and js with new names, so the browser will force download instead of taking these files from memory.

Comment: Yes that's 1 portion of my solution. But We have given facility to our customers that they can override the image/css from the UI. So in that case grunt won't be able to do my tasks.
BTW, I have fixed the issue using Etag.
Refer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag

Answer (score 0):

You can add version to your html files

```
app.factory('preventTemplateCache', function () {
    return {
        'request': function (config) {
            if (config.url.indexOf('partials') !== -1) {
                config.url = config.url + '?t=' + 101;
            }
            return config;
        }
    }
})
```

and also give version to .js files as

```
 <script src='app.js?v=101'></script>
```

101 is version number

Comment: here 'partials' is folder containing html files

Comment: Everytime i need to modify this version when i update my product?

Comment: Than it will be hard to manage, I have hundreds of html & js files.

Comment: add above code in your app.js it will give version to all html , and for js files you just have to replace all files version with new version you can user find and replace with any editor like vscode or sublime.